# Font style of caption/title of CDialog

Tags: c++, mfc, cdialog

I want to change the font style and font size of title/caption of Dialog(Derived from CDialog).Since caption/title is not associated with any resource id so i can't even use SetFont().Tell

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I suggest to avoid "urgent", "ASAP", we appreciate more context (is that  MFC?) and what you have done so far, what failed what succeeded.

Comment: Do skinning of entire dialog (use without system border) , which is pretty easy, by associating with a bitmap.

Comment: This absolutely NOT easy (see above linked page). Avoid it and refer to Windows standard styling, which is a good reason not to change your dialog's title bar.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a base class that does this, and then have all your dialog classes derive from this one.  As long as you don't change the help id (m_nIDHelp), it should work for base classes. If not, you could add your own member variable to the base class to hold the ID of the dialog.

```
#include <afxpriv.h>

INT_PTR CModifyDialogDlg::DoModal()
{
   CDialogTemplate templ;
   if (!templ.Load(MAKEINTRESOURCE(m_nIDHelp))) // it could be different, but probably isn't
      return -1;

   templ.SetFont(_T("Comic Sans MS"), 16);

   m_lpszTemplateName = NULL;
   InitModalIndirect(templ.m_hTemplate);
   return __super::DoModal();
}
```

Comment: And CModifyDialogDlg must be derived from CDialog ? Right?

Comment: Sorry, but this attempt changes the font for items *inside* the dialog, but not for the caption.

Comment: Is derived from CDialog, but possibly CDialogEx.too, or another dialog class derived from either of those two.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - I'm failing to format a comment - all hints I found don't work... So I post it as an answer here:

And another note: If you want to change the font for items in the dialog, don't refer to the help id, but to the resource id. Like this:

```
INT_PTR CModifyDialogDlg::DoModal()
{
    dlgtemplate.Load(m_lpszTemplateName);
    dlgtemplate.SetFont(ms_DefaultFontFace, (WORD)m_LogFontHeight);
    DLGTEMPLATE *pDlgTemplate = (DLGTEMPLATE*)GlobalLock(dlgtemplate.m_hTemplate);
    m_lpszTemplateName = NULL;
    BOOL retVal = InitModalIndirect(pDlgTemplate);
    GlobalUnlock(dlgtemplate.m_hTemplate);
    return __super::DoModal();
}
```